# Using one socket for peer to peer communication

Tags: sockets, p2p

I want to write a peer to peer network application and have the following problem.

Two nodes in the network, A and B are trying to establish a connection to each other at the same time. When they both accept the connection of the other, there will be two TCP sockets opened.

Only one socket should be used for the communication between the two, because it is enough to communicate in both directions. What is an elegant solution to this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should not be trying to establish two simultaneous connections at the same time.  That is a flaw in your p2p design.  The two peers need to coordinate with each other (such as by exchanging messages via a central server that they are both connected to and knows who they both are).  A decision needs to be made first about who is listening and who is connecting.  One peer only opens a listening socket and that info gets sent to the other peer so it knows where to connect.  If that conection fails (ie, the listening peer is behind a NAT/firewall), the peers need to be notified and a decision made to swap roles.  The previously-connecting peer now opens a listening socket and that info gets sent to the previously-listening peer so it knows where to connect.  If that connection fails (ie, the now-listening peer is also behind a NAT/firewall), then a direct connection between the two peers is not possible without additional help (NAT hole punching, for instance).  In some situations, a direct connection is simply not possible, so data being exchanged between them would have to be proxied through the central server.

Comment: Thank you very much. I thaught I could get away using a simpler method. Having a central server "mediating" between the both would make another protocol necessary, and that means more development effort and introduction of more complexity into the whole story. However, I think it is best to go that way. Thanks.

Comment: Most p2p protocols I know work the way I outlined. Both peers connect to a shared server that keeps track of their connection info, and then the peers ask the server for that info and let it coordinate the direct connections as needed.